# How to get public data from Google plus

Tags: google-plus, bigdata

I have a project that involves having public data downloaded from Google plus, can you give me a reference on how I can download like 1 GB of any type of public data from Google plus?

The data can be posts or circles information. I've tried to work with developer tools but the far I got is downloading my own profile information but what I need is public data.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is no truly "public" data on Google+.

Every stream is unique to a user.

Try viewing the site without logging in, and you'll see what I mean.

Since users have the ability to block other users from viewing even their "public" posts, before Google shows you a post they check to see if you're on the blocked list. For them to be able to do that, you have to be logged in.

Your best bet would be to create a dummy account and only look at your nearby stream or What's Hot.

Otherwise you'd need to circle users, and that would create the stream. G+ is not like twitter. There's no firehose to speak of.

To programmatically cull data, you would have to use [their API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/), but even then their HTTP API limits you to 20 results per search and you have to provide a query.

You could get up to 100 results per user if you picked individuals and got their userids, but again there's not a programmatic way to get a bulk dump.

You could randomly select users by using an activity search for a dictionary entry, and then seed that into the activity listing api... something like (in pure pseudocode)

```
for Random word in dictionary
    group = userids from GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?query=[word]
    for userid in group
        GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/[userid]/activities/collection/public
```

Actual code would of course depend on the language.

Comment: what do you mean by activity search for a dictionary entry?

Comment: since search uses whole word search, you would need to choose an actual word to search for. In the website you can use punctuation, which gives better results, but I tried it in the api tester and that didn't work.